# Run to user code in IDA

Tags: ida

Is there a way, as ollydbg provides, to run untill user code (programmer code) with IDA PRO ?
You can do that in several ways in olly, like setting a breakpoint on the .text section of main module.

Comment: What do you mean by user code ?

Comment: @ws I guess OP means non-standard-library-code

Comment: @Nordwald There are different users(programmers), some of them are writing standard libraries :)

Comment: @ws This is just the way ollydbg implements this function. Every code in the mapped executable is considered 'user code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is that IDA provides the exact same option :
Open the segment view subwindow and set a breakpoint on a memory region.
Whenever non-library code (thanks to a comment on question for rephrasing with more accuracy what i meant) is hit, the debugger will break. Very usefull for instance for resuming after user input or IPC WM_COPYDATA procedure calls.